# $push to update nested array in Mongoose and return added object

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

The structure of my MongoDB is something like this...

```
Database (Job Application Database)
   ...
   Nested Array of Objects (Applicants)
      ...
      Another Nested Array of Objects (Comments)
```

I have this code working fine to update the nested array

```
JobApplication.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: new ObjectId(data.job_app_id), 'applicants._id' : new ObjectId(data.selected_applicant_id) },
   {'$push': {'applicants.$.comments': data.message}},
   {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
   function(err, model) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(model);
   }
)
```

The problem I'm having is it doesn't return the added object. The reason why I am not just returning `data.message` is because I need the _id of the object. Is there a way of returning the added object?

Comment: The problem here is "upsert". Think for a moment of why this could be a problem when you are looking for content within an array. There is a very rational reason why these two do not mix well.

Comment: @BlakesSeven care to explain the reason please?

Answer (score 0):

```
`JobApplication.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: new ObjectId(data.job_app_id), 'applicants._id' : new ObjectId(data.selected_applicant_id) },
   {'$push': {'applicants.$.comments': data.message}},
   {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
   function(err, model) {
if(err) return JSON.stringify(err)
        if(model){
console.log(model) }
)`
```